# RPi pin being tripped by static electricity?

Tags: raspberry-pi, external, hardware

I'm writing a program that will run a timer until the user plugs a wire into two ports and presses a big red button. At home, my program works pretty well, but when many people are in the same room, they are able to stop the timer by just touching the ports. This is somewhat problematic and I don't know how to combat it.

In a nutshell, My GPIO pins are set up like this:

```
def pressBigButton(pin):
        self.paused = 1
        self.label.configure(fg='#FFFFFF')self.switchPin = 4

GPIO.setup(self.switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(self.switchPin,GPIO.FALLING)
GPIO.add_event_callback(self.switchPin,pressBigButton)
```

From what I understand, this should set the pin to HIGH voltage and should fall when the user presses the button. My hope was that this would eliminate the possibility of static electricity causing a spike in voltage, tripping the timer prematurely. In addition, I connected the terminals to the GND pin, but this doesn't seem to help.

[image: simple diagram]

I may have some of the symbols wrong. Apologies.

If you need the full code, i have it here.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import math
import time

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # make it cover the entire screen
        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=9, height=3, font=("Courier Bold", 160), fg='brown', bg='black')
        self.label.pack()
        self.startTime=time.time()
        print "startTime", time.time()
        #self.total can be changed to alter the timer's length, but it should never be changed in runtime
        #Default = 3600
        self.total = 3600
        self.remaining = self.total
        #timerMode 1 = standard clock, 2 = percentage
        self.timerMode = 2
        self.paused = 1

        def pressSpace(event):
            if(self.paused == 0 and self.remaining > 0):
                self.paused = 1
                self.label.configure(fg='#FFFFFF')
            else:
                self.paused = 0
                self.label.configure(fg='#0000FF')
                self.mainLoop()

        def pressEsc(event):
            if(self.paused == 1):
                self.destroy()

        def pressBigButton(pin):
            self.paused = 1
            self.label.configure(fg='#FFFFFF')

        #bind spacebar to pause the timer
        self.bind("<space>", pressSpace)

        #bind Esc to kill the process
        self.bind("<Escape>", pressEsc)

        #initialize GPIO pin
        self.switchPin = 4
        GPIO.setup(self.switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.switchPin,GPIO.FALLING)
        GPIO.add_event_callback(self.switchPin,pressBigButton)
        self.pinStatus = GPIO.input(self.switchPin)

        self.setTime() #sets the initial clock before unpausing
        self.mainLoop()

    def mainLoop(self):        

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            #Time has expired. Players lose
            self.paused = 1
            self.label.configure(text="TIME!", font=("Courier Bold", 160), fg='#000000', bg='#FF0000')
        else:
            #There is still time on the clock. Check if player has flipped the switch to stop the timer
            if not(GPIO.input(self.switchPin)):
                self.paused = 1
                self.label.configure(fg='white')

            strTimer = self.setTime()
            self.label.configure(text= strTimer)
            if(self.paused == 0): #Check if the timer is toggled to pause
                self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
                self.after(1000, self.mainLoop)
                #time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - self.startTime) % 1.0))
                self.setColor()

    def setColor(self):
        fremaining = (1.0*self.remaining)
        blueDown = self.twoDigitHex(255*(fremaining/self.total))
        redUp = self.twoDigitHex(255-(255*(fremaining/self.total)))
        color = "#" + redUp + "00" + blueDown
        self.label.configure(fg=color)

    def twoDigitHex(self, number):
        return '%02x' % number

    def setTime(self):
        if(self.timerMode == 1):
            #STANDARD CLOCK
            #creates a readout of constant length regardless of significant digits
            h = str(math.trunc(self.remaining/3600))
            remainder = (math.trunc(self.remaining % 3600))
            m = str(remainder / 60)
            s = str(remainder % 60)

            time = []
            index = 0
            time.append(h)
            time.append(m)
            time.append(s)
            for i in time:
                if (len(i)==1):#If a number is 1 digit, make it 2 digits
                    time[index] = ('0' + i)
                index += 1
            if(time[0] == '01'):
                return ('1:' + time[1] + ':' + time[2])
            elif(time[0] == '00' and time[1] != '00'):
                return (time[1] + ':' + time[2])
            elif(time[0]== '00' and time[1]== '00'):
                return (time[2])
            else:
                return (time[0] + ':' + time[1] + ':' + time[2])

        elif(self.timerMode == 2):
            #PERCENT CLOCK
            percent = (100*(self.remaining / (self.total*(1.0))))
            return(str('%.1f%%' % percent))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

tl;dr: GPIO.FALLING sometimes trips when users touch terminals A and B. I suspect static electricity. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i completely understood your problem but if you can change the pin arrangement and the position of the resistor you could use it as a pull down and you would need to change the code to detect a rising edge.
So you have to change this:

```
GPIO.setup(self.switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(self.switchPin,GPIO.FALLING)
```

to this

```
GPIO.setup(self.switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(self.switchPin,GPIO.RISING)
```

And In your circuit you would need to connect terminal `A` to a `3.3V` pin instead of the `GND` pin and remove the 10k resistor. If you still get wrong results you could try to connect the 10k resistor to `GND` and the input pin in this case pin `4`.

I do not have enough rep to post the picture but here is the link:
[schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXAHI.png)
(ignore the labels for pin 1 and 2 on the connector, it was just the only one i could find quickly)
Hope this helps